# method for removing spaces in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method to remove spaces in a given String. this is my code right now:

```
public class sorter {

    public static String nameConvertion(String name) {
        name = name.replaceAll("\\s","");
        return name;
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String name = "    123 123 123 123  ";
        nameConvertion(name);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't remove the spaces, what am i missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: You have to reassign the result to your string: `name = nameConvertion(name);`

Comment: `String str = nameConvertion(name);` You need to assign to some variable what `nameConvertion(name);` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the return value of your `nameConvention`-method

Your current workflow is:

1. give a String to `nameConvention`
2. remove spaces
3. return result
4. ignore returned result